# Why does this timestamp comparing always evaluate to true?

Tags: php, if-statement, timestamp, compare

I have the following code to see if the allotted time has passed.
For my demo it should all evaluate to false and nothing should happen.
What happens ever is that it parses to true, even inf I compare it with >=

Why do I get this strange behaviour?

```
$data = '[{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988643},{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988649},{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988650},{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988664},{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988682},{"ip":"80.61.150.173","endtime":1343988723}]';
$json = json_decode($data,true);
foreach($json as $key => $obj)
    {
    var_dump($obj);
    echo "<BR>";
    var_dump(time());
    echo "<BR>";
    if($obj['endtime'] <= time());
        {
        echo "<BR>bliep<P>";
        }
    }
```

This code evaluates to this result:

> array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988643) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988649) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep
>
> array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988650) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep
>
> array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988664) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep
>
> array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988682) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep
>
> array(2) { ["ip"]=> string(13) "80.61.150.173" ["endtime"]=>
>   int(1343988723) }
>   int(1343981967)
>
> bliep

As you can see, there are all blieps there that shouldn't be there.
The timestamps are ints, the current time is smaller than the saved time.
It should compare easily, but it evaluates always to true, whilst now is < than the stored timestamp.

What's going on here?

It's not my server because this code also evaluates to true on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Try echoing $obj['endtime'] - time() instead of bliep to see where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there's a typo `;` at the end if your `if` statement.

Should've been

```
if($obj['endtime'] <= time());
```

instead of

```
if($obj['endtime'] <= time())
```

Comment: omg... I feel so stupid right now... It never threw up an error...
*blush* Will accept your answer in 11 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
if($obj['endtime'] <= time());
```

Should be

```
if($obj['endtime'] <= time())//without the semicolon
```

---

though you have an answer, I thought it would be nice to know why it didn't throw an error.

essentially `if($obj['endtime'] <= time());` is interpreted as the *short* or one-line if statement:

```
if($obj['endtime'] <= time())
    echo 'foo';
else
    echo 'bar';
```

But since there are no statements between the `if` statement and the semicolon, php will just carry on, and -rather annoyingly IMO- ignore the curly braces. I'm not sure about this, but if you had an `else{}` on the next line, you might have gotten an error...
A nice example of how support for various syntaxes can give you fierce headaches. That said, I like your coding style, keeping opening and closing curly's on new lines. improves readability IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I would have at least expected a "warning" about unneded syntax or something for the curly braces. But alas, it didn't.
Thank you for the answer and the compliment!